# /bin/sh: 1: composer: not found

Tags: laravel, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to build a Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7

RUN mkdir -p /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app
WORKDIR /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app


COPY composer.json /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app
RUN composer install

COPY . /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

But when i run the build command it says:

```
docker build -t lar-app .
/bin/sh: 1: composer: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c composer install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

But when I type just composer it is properly displaying the information
I guess the problem is with the command:

```
RUN composer install
```

Here I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The docker image that you're trying to create doesn't have composer installed. The `RUN composer install` tries to run `composer install` on the image itself, not the host machine. So, in essence, you need to install composer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Stacktrace says, install composer before running `composer` command.

I've added these lines:

```
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/1b137f8bf6db3e79a38a5bc45324414a6b1f9df2/web/installer -O - -q | php -- --quiet
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

So your Dockerfile will be:

```
FROM php:7

# Install composer:
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/1b137f8bf6db3e79a38a5bc45324414a6b1f9df2/web/installer -O - -q | php -- --quiet
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN mkdir -p /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app
WORKDIR /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app

COPY composer.json /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app
RUN composer install

COPY . /home/winpc/test/laravelApp/app

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

Comment: mv: cannot stat 'composer.phar': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: I think composer.phar is not downloading properly

Comment: I've modified the Dockerfile. I've put the installation at the very beginning. Can you please try again?

Comment: RUN   apk update \
 &&   apk add ca-certificates wget \
 &&   update-ca-certificates

Comment: Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

Comment: Yah thank you...Now i think the problem is with my php version

Comment: You need to install mcrypt for php in the Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration...Problem solved